# Use infrared LED of the proximity sensor as a remote control

Tags: applications, remote-control, proximity-sensor

The proximity sensor present in almost all Android phones have a infrared light and a sensor. There exists an app that use this infrared to act as IR remote control? If no, it's possible to construct an app to do that?

Comment: The Android API only return 0 and 1 for the proximity sensor, but I don't know if that is the real output of the sensor or if it is interpreted by Android. On a rooted device direct hardware access may reveal more details on the sensor data, but I don't think the sensor is fast enough for IR signals which use about 30KHz or more as base signal.

Comment: I mean if it's possible to use an app to control that infrared led using it to control other devices like TV.